# Sorting multiple sections of a json

Tags: json, powershell, sorting

I am attempting to sort a .json.  The json should be sorted first by "Name" and then a sort of everything in "Products".  The sort would need to be done via PowerShell.

I have attempted using a derivative of [powershell sort json by value with Sort-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178265/powershell-sort-json-by-value-with-sort-object) but with no success.

```
$json = Get-Content '.\.vscode\driverDetails.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
$json.Name = $json.Name | Sort-Object Name 
$json.Products = $json.Products | Sort-Object Products
$json | ConvertTo-Json
```

The json itself should be sorted by "Name"
Everything under "Products" is sorted.

Example below

Original Json:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "HPE Smart Array P824i-p MR 64-bit controller driver for Microsoft Windows 2016 edition.",
    "cpFile": "cp034411",
    "version": "6.714.18.0",
    "OS": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016",
    "Products": [
      "HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen10 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant DL560 Gen10 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant DL385 Gen10 Server\n",
      "HPE ProLiant ML350 Gen10 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen10 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant DL580 Gen10 Server"
    ],
    "Description": "This driver, MegaSAS2, provides Windows 64-bit support for HPE Smart Array P824i-p MR 64-bit controller",
    "Category": "Driver - Storage Controller"
  },
  {
    "Name": "HPE H2xx SAS/SATA Host Bus Adapter Driver for 64-bit Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Editions",
    "cpFile": "cp037731",
    "version": "2.68.64.2",
    "OS": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016",
    "Products": [
      "HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen9 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant DL560 Gen9 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant ML350 Gen9 Server"
    ],
    "Description": "This driver, LSI_SAS2, provides Windows Server 2016 support for HPE H2xx SAS/SATA Host Bus Adapter. ",
    "Category": "Driver - Storage Controller"
  }
]
```

Sorted Json:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "HPE H2xx SAS/SATA Host Bus Adapter Driver for 64-bit Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Editions",
    "cpFile": "cp037731",
    "version": "2.68.64.2",
    "OS": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016",
    "Products": [
      "HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen9 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen9 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant DL560 Gen9 Server",
      "HPE ProLiant ML350 Gen9 Server"
    ],
    "Description": "This driver, LSI_SAS2, provides Windows Server 2016 support for HPE H2xx SAS/SATA Host Bus Adapter. ",
    "Category": "Driver - Storage Controller"
  },
    {
      "Name": "HPE Smart Array P824i-p MR 64-bit controller driver for Microsoft Windows 2016 edition.",
      "cpFile": "cp034411",
      "version": "6.714.18.0",
      "OS": "Microsoft Windows Server 2016",
      "Products": [
        "HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen10 Server",
        "HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen10 Server",
        "HPE ProLiant DL385 Gen10 Server",
        "HPE ProLiant DL560 Gen10 Server",
        "HPE ProLiant DL580 Gen10 Server",
        "HPE ProLiant ML350 Gen10 Server"
      ],
      "Description": "This driver, MegaSAS2, provides Windows 64-bit support for HPE Smart Array P824i-p MR 64-bit controller",
      "Category": "Driver - Storage Controller"
    }
]
```

Comment: Where is the coding attempt at this that you mentioned? This is also too ambiguous. Sort based off what in the products? The gen? The model? How would it know what to sort it by in other words.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I have updated the question to be more specific.  Please let me know if it is still to ambiguous.

Comment: like `$json | ConvertTo-Json | Sort Name, Products`?

Comment: `$json | ForEach-Object { $_.Products = $_.Products | Sort-Object; $_ } | Sort-Object Name | ConvertTo-Json
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *The json itself should be sorted by "Name"*:

```
$Json = $Json |Sort-Object Name
```

To *sort of everything in "Products"*:

```
$Json.Foreach{ $_.Products = $_.Products |Sort-Object }
```